# I'm new to react-native. I need to create a layout/screen like these. Could you tell me which components should I use and any relevant tutorial?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

[Screenshots #1 and #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EbvQ.png)

So, screen#1 should become visible upon clicking '+' in the toolbar and screen#2 should be visible upon swiping from left to right or clicking on three bars at the left top in toolbar. I want to use react-native-navigation library only.

1. How can I add '+' symbol in the toolbar?
2. I also need to store the data initially in Async storage. How to do so?
3. Please let me know which react-native components or react-native-navigation components should I use and if there are any relevant tutorials/video tutorials available regarding these?

I would be thankful for your help.

Comment: For async storage you can use this [package](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage) made by the react-native-community

Answer (score 0):

For the first question in the picture, you can use [`React-navigation` to configure the headers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html) on the screen. For more information, see the link.

If you click on the plus button, you can implement it similarly using [`Modal`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html). This is in the Reaction Native prop.

And the second question in the picture is, again, using `React-navigation`, you can build a [drawerNavigator](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/drawer-based-navigation.html).

And the answer to the second question on the questionnaire is [asynchronous storage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage). For more information, see the link.

Answer (score 0):

Use a modal class instead. This might be what you're looking for

```
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal
```